# some thoughts on ajaxcontrolkit and alternatives

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

On clicking ajaxcontroltoolkit tag, I noticed most of the questions are unanswered. It seems nobody cares about this toolkit or nobody uses it.

I was searching for a solution to famous character duplication after refocus in masked edit extender. I found many questions on that asked nearly 3 years ago. All are unanswered and problem still exists. It's just incredible!

What are your thoughts on this toolkit. Is it just a buggy toolkit that is not supported well? What are the other choices? What do you use?

Answer (score 1):

There are many client-side JavaScript UI frameworks, to name a few:

- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)
- [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html)
- [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/)

But if you want a framework that integrates with server-side ASP.NET Web Forms, than you need to look elsewhere, for example at [Telerik ASP.NET Ajax Controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx). Google for more.

As for the ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit, it's open source and hosted on [Codeplex](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/). Is your issue listed on the Issue Tracker? If not, try reporting it there if you think it's a bug. Your last resort may be to contact one of the project [contributors](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/team/view).